# How do I disable the KDB+ debugger for non-interactive sessions?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Sometimes, when my q script has an error, the debugger prompt appears: `q))`.  I need to type `\` to exit the debugger.

This is OK during interactive sessions, but breaks my scheduled (non-interactive) runs from crontab.

Can I disable the debugger for non-interactive runs?  My *Google-fu* fails me.

Ref: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/BackSlash

Answer (score 4):

You should use [trap](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#trap) to respond to errors.

For periodic tasks in cron I like to fire a HTTP/IPC request at a running q instance instead of spinning up a q core since cron doesn't serialise. Using IPC means trapping is controlled by [\e](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#e-error-trap-clients).

I might also prefer using [the timer](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer), depending on how periodic we are talking.